# adding div after float

Tags: html, css

I have created 3 divs side by side using floats as seen below, however I am unsure on how to add a single div that has a width 100% and some height underneath these. I tried simply creating a div however it simply doesn't appear and am not sure if it's a simple coding error or there is something more I need to do

```
.first-div {
 width:33.33%;
 height:150px;
 float:left;
 background-color:pink;
}

.second-div {
 width:33.33%;
 height:150px;
 float:left;
 background-color:blue;
}

.third-div {
width:33.33%;
height:150px;
float:left;
background-color:purple;
}
```

Comment: Adding HTML for context is always helpful with CSS/javascript questions. Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Add `clear: both;` to the fourth DIV

```css
.first-div {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: pink;
}

.second-div {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}

.third-div {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: purple;
}

.fourth-div {
  clear: both;
  background: yellow;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div"></div>
<div class="second-div"></div>
<div class="third-div"></div>
<div class="fourth-div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.first-div {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: pink;
}

.second-div {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}

.third-div {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: purple;
}

.fourth-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div">shashi</div>
<div class="second-div">shashi</div>
<div class="third-div">shashi</div>
<div class="fourth-div">shashi</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the first three Divs inside of their own div. set the position if this new parent div to relative and the position of the 3 divs inside of it to absolute.

Finally, place a fourth div but itself after the set of three by itself and set its position to relative.

This is the most simplistic answer that requires less typing and leave less room for code that will interfere in future interactions

```
<div id=columnSet>
    <div class=column></div>
    <div class=column></div>
    <div class=column></div>
</div>
<div id=singleDiv></div>
```

Set the width of the div id=columnSet to 100% and the divs inside to create the columns 33% respectively. The divs will automatically line up.

Best of luck with your coding!

Answer (score 0):

Clearfix should be the solution to your problem. Which you can read up on here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp and I would recommend wrapping the first 3 divs up in a clearfix div.

```css
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.first-div {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: pink;
}

.second-div {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}

.third-div {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: purple;
}

.last-div {
  margin: 25px 0 0 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="first-div"> </div>
  <div class="second-div"> </div>
  <div class="third-div"> </div>
</div>

<div class="last-div"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another solution, create a new `<div>` element with a `.clearfix` class.

```
.clearfix{
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
```

Or better:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
}

.clearfix:after {
clear:both;
}
```

This hack will be useful everytime you want to make separation like this in you page. This hack is used in many frameworks ([Bootstrap for example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-clearfix)).

```css
/*Clearfix*/
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
}

.clearfix:after {
clear:both;
}
/*My css*/
.first-div {
width:33.33%;
height:150px;
float:left;
background-color:pink;
}

.second-div {
width:33.33%;
height:150px;
float:left;
background-color:blue;
}

.third-div {
width:33.33%;
height:150px;
float:left;
background-color:purple;
}
.forth-div{
  height:150px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div"></div>
<div class="second-div"></div>
<div class="third-div"></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="forth-div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
.first-div {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: pink;
}

.second-div {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 150px;

  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}

.third-div {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: purple;
}

.fourth-div {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: yellow;
  height: 150px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="first-div"></div>
<div class="second-div"></div>
<div class="third-div"></div>
<div class="fourth-div" ></div>

 
</body>
</html>
```